# FBLogin libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dylib

I've configured everything based on FB doco https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ But my app crashes after clicking on `FBLoginButton`, Could you please advise what I'm missing in my code?
Here is my pod

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

I'm developing based on `swift 4.2`, `xcode 10` and `ios 12`
And here is my code for AppDelegate and ViewController:

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    return handled
}

//...
}
```

and ViewController

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(loginButton)

    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)

    loginButton.delegate = self
        }

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged in with facebook...")
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Did log out of facebook")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed to add APP_ID in the following config in `info.plist` After adding app_ID, the app connected to FB.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb{APP_ID}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```